# Delete customers domain extension only (in .csv file)

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, csv-simple

I have a list of my customers emails and want to remove some that end in .br for example. I would normally do the following command:

```
sed -i '/.br/d' customers.csv
```

But that would also delete a customers email that was something like `xyz.br@gmail.com`.

Example of a customer detail is:

```
"Phone Number","EMAIL@XYZ.com","NAME"
```

How would I delete only customers emails that end in `.br`?

Comment: Search for `\.br"` (or `\.br",`, if there's a risk that NAME might end with `.br`).

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to read the file as a header-less CSV file, and then filter it so that only records whose 2nd field does not end with `.br` are kept:

```bash
mlr --csv -N filter '$2 !=~ "\.br$"' file
```

If you want to quote all fields in the output, add `--quote-all` after `-N`.  If you have headers, then remove `-N` and use the header name in place of `$2`, e.g. `$email !=~ "\.br$"`.

Testing:

```bash
$ cat file
"Phone Number","EMAIL@XYZ.com","NAME"
"Phone Number2","EMAIL@XYZ.br","NAME2"
"Phone Number3","EMAIL@XYZ.abr","NAME3"
"Phone Number","EMAIL@ABCbr.com","NAME"
"Phone Number","EMAIL@XYZ.com","NAME.br"
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N filter '$2 !=~ "\.br$"' file
Phone Number,EMAIL@XYZ.com,NAME
Phone Number3,EMAIL@XYZ.abr,NAME3
Phone Number,EMAIL@ABCbr.com,NAME
Phone Number,EMAIL@XYZ.com,NAME.br
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the **`.`** so that it does not match any character to make sure it will not match something like "name@add.abr" for example.
You can also look for `.br` that appears *after* an `@`.

Try

```
 sed -i '/".*\@[^"]*\.br"/d' customer.csv
```

Here is an example run:

```
~$ echo '"Phone Number","EMAIL@XYZ.com","NAME"
> "Phone Number2","EMAIL@XYZ.br","NAME2"
> "Phone Number3","EMAIL@XYZ.abr","NAME3"
> "Phone Number","EMAIL@ABCbr.com","NAME"
> "Phone Number","EMAIL@XYZ.com","NAME.br"' > customers.csv

~$ cat customers.csv
"Phone Number","EMAIL@XYZ.com","NAME" 
"Phone Number2","EMAIL@XYZ.br","NAME2"  <-- should get deleted
"Phone Number3","EMAIL@XYZ.abr","NAME3"
"Phone Number","EMAIL@ABCbr.com","NAME"
"Phone Number","EMAIL@XYZ.com","NAME.br"

~$ sed -i '/".*@.*\.br"/d' customer.csv 

~$ cat customers.csv 
"Phone Number","EMAIL@XYZ.com","NAME"
"Phone Number3","EMAIL@XYZ.abr","NAME3"
"Phone Number","EMAIL@ABCbr.com","NAME"
"Phone Number","EMAIL@XYZ.com","NAME.br"
```

Comment: sed -i '/".*@.*\..br"/d' customers.csv did not work.

Comment: sed -i '/@.*\.br"/d' customers.csv just deleted the whole file content.

Comment: I updated the expression.. And showed example output.